# Execute an export command created from a json using jq

Tags: json, environment-variables, sh, jq

I have an input json as below with the keys changing dynamically, the only static content in the key is the text '_GROUP_NAME' and '_VERSION'

```
[
    {
      "PREPROCESS_GROUP_NAME": "preprocess-group-name",
      "PREPROCESS_VERSION": 2
    },
    {
      "CLASSIFIER_GROUP_NAME": "classifier-group-name",
      "CLASSIFIER_VERSION": 2
    },
    {
      "ABC_GROUP_NAME": "abc-group-name",
      "ABC_VERSION": 2
    }
]
```

I want to export the key value pair as environment variables. Basically I want to read the json above and execute commands as

```
export PREPROCESS_GROUP_NAME='preprocess-group-name'
export PREPROCESS_VERSION=2
export CLASSIFIER_GROUP_NAME='classifier-group-name'
export CLASSIFIER_VERSION=2
export ABC_GROUP_NAME='abc-group-name'
export ABC_VERSION=2
```

I am looking for a solution which will create export commands based on dynamically generated keys and values.

Answer (score 3):

With your JSON as input,

```
jq -r '.[] | to_entries[] | "export \(.key)=\(.value|@sh)"'
```

produces:

```
export PREPROCESS_GROUP_NAME='preprocess-group-name'
export PREPROCESS_VERSION=2
export CLASSIFIER_GROUP_NAME='classifier-group-name'
export CLASSIFIER_VERSION=2
```

These commands can then be evaluated by the shell in whichever way you deem appropriate.

A possibly-safer alternative would be:

```
while read -r key ; do
    read -r value
    export "$key"="$value"
done < <(< input.json jq -r '.[] | to_entries[] | .key, .value')
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am able to get the output. Trying to figure out how I can execute the generated export statements also.

Comment: while read -r key ; do
    read -r value
    export "$key"="$value"
done < <(json | jq -r '.[] | to_entries[] | .key, .value, "\n"')

This command fails as empty values are also retrieved as key and value, getting error as 

bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier

Comment: There was a spurious `"\n"` that I have removed.

Comment: Still the environment variables are not getting created.

After executing above command if I test either using anyone of below command is not printing the environment variable value as it is not defined

```
echo $PREPROCESS_GROUP_NAME
```

or using below code

```
if [[ -z "${PREPROCESS_GROUP_NAME}" ]]; then
 var1="env variable undefined"
else
 var1="${PREPROCESS_GROUP_NAME}"
fi

echo $var1 --> Prints as 'env variable undefined'
```

Comment: I have clarified the `while ... done ... ` code. I wasn't sure where the JSON was coming from.

Comment: Thanks it worked. However one more issue, the command is execute if executed in shell. If I move the command to a shell script, I am getting error as 'syntax error near unexpected token `<''. What could I possibly missing??

Comment: I've checked it works as a bash script (#!/bin/bash).  Make sure there is no space in the token `<(`